# Why am I not able to scroll to the bottom of a page when changing Device Metrics in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, media-queries, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to use the Device Metrics feature in Chrome Dev Tools to help me find and fix problems with media queries in a site's CSS. I'm able to successfully change the Device Metrics but when I do I'm not able to scroll to the bottom of the page I'm viewing. Reloading the page doesn't do anything. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out after doing some more research:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=171695

It seems if you set the height in Device Metrics to a value larger than the available height in your Chrome window the browser behaves in this fashion. Lowering the height to be less than your window height resolves this problem.